# data source explorer derby embedded db bootPassword

Tags: eclipse, derby

Is there any way to create a Derby Embedded DB with the **dataEncryption=true** and **bootPassword=somePassword**, through the eclipse data source explorer?

I tried the Optional properties, under the optional tab but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I hate "works for me" answers, but... works for me :)

Try checking:

- if the *dataEncryption* parameter precedes *bootPassword*,
- *bootPassword* should be at least 8 characters,

My *Apache Derby Core Plugin for Eclipse* version is 10.8.2.1, I'm using *Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.2 Default* and Derby version 10.8.1.2. I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: i did exactly the same but didn't work ... did you use the optional tab ?

Comment: Actually the data base gets created for me, and it looks fine, but what i mean by "didn't work", is that when i try to connect from my client application without providing the bootPassword, it connects with no problem, which means that the encryption didn't take effect ...